# Can't use it with Angular 8. Trying to see Component and tree structure but it gives error in console

Tags: debugging, angular8, augury

Augury helps Angular developers visualize the application through component trees and visual debugging tools.but I'm unable to use it with Angular 8.and it gives an error in the console

[image: Console error of augury]

I have tried upgrading the console and also sent a bug report to the team but it doesn't work.

It should work and visualize the tree structure of models and components

Comment: The question is quite broad and thus it is hard to give a valuable feedback. you should at least report the console error.

Comment: I've  added the screenshot of the console error which i'm getting.